# Problem Specifying the tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I am relatively new to database design. I have a database which has the following design

I have specified the the tables in SQL as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE Piece
(identifier INT NOT NULL Unique,
 value      INT NOT NULL,
 the date it was acquited DATE,
 the date it was made DATE,
 PRIMARY KEY (identifier));

CREATE TABLE Person
(name VARCHAR(50),
 person_id INT NOT NULL Unique,
 biography VARCHAR (50),
 date of birth DATE,
 date of death DATE,
 PRIMARY KEY (person_id));

CREATE TABLE Jewel
(code INT NOT NULL Unique,
 gem type VARCHAR (50),
 weight INT,
 quality VARCHAR (50),
 color VARCHAR (50),
 description VARCHAR (50),
 PRIMARY KEY (code));

CREATE TABLE Gem
(type VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 hardness INT,
 density  INT,
 FOREIGN KEY (type) references JEWEL(gem type));

CREATE TABLE Ownership
(person VARCHAR (50),
 piece  INT,
 start of ownership DATE,
 end of ownership   DATE,
 FOREIGN KEY (person) references PERSON(person_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (piece) references PIECE(identifier));
```

My question is

1.) How can I specify a primary key to the GEM table as all the 3 attributes are not unique, should I have to create a new attribute like Gem_id, as I would prefer to use the existing attributes and not add a new attribute.

2.) I have used person_id attribute in the person table to make it unique and use it as a primary key, is there another way to create a primary key for the person table without adding the extra attribute and obviously I cant include constraints to the existing attribute and make it UNIQUE

3.) Is all integrity constraints and data types right ? Is my design flawed in any way.

Comment: Is this homework? and what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I m using Microsoft SQL Server. Its a design for a website project in my schl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes you can create a multi column primary key (composite primary key) but it will be unique.  Something like this should do it:

```
CREATE TABLE Gem
(type VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 hardness INT,
 density  INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (type , hardness, density ),
 FOREIGN KEY (type) references JEWEL(gem type));
```

2) There are other ways to create a primary key for the Person table but I would not recommend it.  Person_id is what I would use here.

3) I would make the following changes to your design:

- Make Person in the ownership table an int rather than a VARCHAR.  If it's a foreign key to `person_id`, then you don't want it to be a VARCHAR.
- Add an int identifier to the Gem table.  `GemTypeId` or something.
- In the jewel table, replace the `gem type` column with your new `GemTypeId` column.

There might be more, but these were the ones that jumped out at me.

It seems like you are trying not to use IDs to represent your data.  Is there a reason for this?  If you continue down this road you may run into data integrity issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I know that keeping an Id for every table is a good design and making it to auto increment , I was just wondering if making the type of gem unique is a good idea as there can be only a finite number of types which can repeat itself.

Comment: If the type of the gem should be unique then give the type column a unique constraint in the Gem table.  I would still use int IDs for everything though.

Comment: "may run into data integrity issues" -- I see more data integrity failures with folk who do use surrogate keys.